# Why does Process.Start show an error message box, even though I redirect the standard error?

Tags: c#

Why does Process.Start show an error message box, even though I redirect the standard error?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.Arguments = Optimizer.GetArgumentsString();
startInfo.FileName = ProjectSettings.OptimizerExe;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;


process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string outpute = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The call System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo) results in this error message box:

[image]

but I don't want that message box to show. If there is an error in the called exe
I want to handle it myself, I don't know where that error message box comes from.

Comment: Let me understand. You want to prevent other application from handling its own exception? Thats' absurd.

Comment: Basically, I don't know where that error message box comes from. It happens on Process.Start. So I call another exe from my program, but then I get this error box, and I don't want this message box to show up.

Comment: So decompile the exe you're starting and prevent it from popping the dialog... Duh.

Comment: What do you mean decompile

Comment: Sorry, it was a bit of a poke at you... The logic that is popping up that dialog is contained in the executable that you're trying to start. It's nothing to do with the standard error output. It's been programmed to pop up a dialog. Without changing the application code of the target executable, you're pretty stuffed. Decompiling and recompiling would be one (very difficult) way of achieving this.

Comment: It's not absurd; If you're automating another process you should be able to control how and if it interacts with the desktop.  Windows has hooks to allow you to do this (for instance you can use the 'CreateDesktop' function to achieve this, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to go that far...)

Answer (score 4):

This message box comes right from the process you started. 
You could check if there is "console" mode of operation for your process - try to start it from the command line with option for help - ( "/?", "/help",...) or contact the customer support of the company that developed the application.

If it is inhouse applicaiton or you have access to the source code - you can modify it and implement the console mode yourself. There are well known techniques how to do it - I will not describe them here as this would different question :)

If there is no console mode and you have no soure code access -  than the process is just not intended to be used like this and you are out of luck. Of course you could make sure a valid license is found and message box does not show - but some other message box can pop up later.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the process you're starting is showing the error box. There's nothing clean you can do about it. It's out of your reach.

The message box exists in a wholy separate message loop, in a completely different process. It has nothing to do with you using `Process.Start` - if you start the exe using `Windows Explorer`, it will still show that dialog. If you do have the license file, make sure you set the `WorkingDirectory` to the correct folder (provided the application actually reads the license from a file) - that might solve your issue.

Redirect standard output will do exactly what it says - it will redirect the standard output pipe. That's basically `Console.WriteLine`/`ReadLine` - it does nothing with GUI.

The same way "standard error" is just another pipe. The application obviously doesn't use it to output errors. It's not required too, and it's not used much in GUI applications.

In reality, both standard output and standard error are features of command line applications, not of GUI applications. If the application isn't designed to work from the command line, you ain't gonna make it :)

Oh, and when you redirect standard output/error, you have to actually read it. Otherwise, if they are used by the application, their buffers will get filled and the application will freeze :)